# How to remove duplicate explicit permission in ntfs

Tags: ntfs, file-permissions

We have a large directory tree (9TB) on an NTFS file system.  The root directory of the tree, say `G:\TreeRoot`, has a duplicate explicit permission.  For example, executing `ICACLS G:\TreeRoot` shows

```
G:\TreeReoot OURDOMAIN\SOME_GROUP:(OI)(CI)(N)
             OURDOMAIN\SOME_GROUP:(OI)(CI)(N)
             OURDOMAIN\SOME_USER:(OI)(CI)(N)
             OURDOMAIN\ANOTHER_GROUP:(OI)(CI)(F)
             BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)(F)
             NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)(F)
```

Note the first entry is a duplicate.  We want to remove the duplicate entry.  Is it possible to remove just one of the entries without removing the second?  Examining the security permissions using the GUI does *not* show both entries.  Using `icacls G:\TreeRoot /remove:d OURDOMAIN\SOME_GROUP` would remove both entries and necessitate adding the (denial) permission back in. (This is not an option for two reasons: one, adding and deleting permissions takes about 10x2=20 hours on the tree, and two, during this time it would leave the directory unprotected, neither of which are options).

Comment: Is it actually causing you any problems to have the duplicate permission? If the answer is no just leave it.

Comment: lol. I knew I'd get that.  Likely the audit groups or the Information Security groups will flag it as an audit finding, and trying to tell them it's not important often gets you in more trouble than it saves.  Otherwise I'd just leave it, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I found an slightly counterintuitive "solution" to this situation: Adding the same (already duplicate) ACL in explorer did actually cleanup the resulting acl so that the duplicate was gone.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: lmao. Well, that is beautiful.  I wish I could test it out and confirm, and then mark as the accepted answer. Someday if I have some extra time - but the directory tree with the permissions issue is now long gone (after a file server replacement...)

Comment: Fantastic, +1. That saved a LOT of work. What an epic fail that `icacls` reports other ACEs than the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

I'm researching how to clean up another messy situation with NTFS that doesn't quite match your scenario, and I suspect you may have either solved it or moved on by now, but just in case you're still working on this, here's a thing that is slightly out of left field but could be worth trying.

For proof-of-concept, initially I suggest trying this on G:\treeroot\some\deep\folder so you don't have to wait for this to be "fixed" through the whole tree....

You mentioned that the explorer UI is not showing the duplicate permissions.  So if you tell explorer to delete whichever of the permsisions it *can* see, does it leave the other one behind?  What do Explorer and iCacls show after trying this?

If the results look 'sane' you could then cautiously go ahead and apply the same approach at G:\TreeRoot

Comment: In our case, when we removed the ACE in question via GUI, *both* ACEs actually got deleted, so I wouldn't recommend your method to anyone.